# WPF RepeatButton with Pressed VisualState

Tags: wpf, expression-blend, visualstatemanager, visualstates, repeatbutton

1) my repeat button visual state is a rectangle which Stroke go's from Transparent to Gray when pressed,

this visual state change occurs only once on Pressed,

since this is a repeat button i would like the visual state change to re occur (like a blinking pressed) over and over while pressing ,
how could i change my visual state to get such an effect

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
    <Grid>
      <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0" To="Pressed"/>
            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
               <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                  <Storyboard>
                     <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF8F8E8E" />
                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  </Storyboard>
               </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
     </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Stroke="Transparent" Fill="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />                                                                      
    </Grid>                 
</ControlTemplate>
```

2) One approach i had in mind is to use GoToStateAction with an EventTrigger on Click event (since the Repeat button re fire that event over and over) ,

but i can't seem to place a GoToStateAction directly on the ControlTemplate , and hadn't had much luck placing it under and EventTrigger under the ControlTemplate .

**So to Conclude iv'e got 2 issues :**

1) A general idea how to solve this issue .

2) My idea requires my to place a GoToStateAction on a ControlTemplate Object , it seems that this can't 
  be done , any ideas how to work around this ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Triggers instead of Visual States

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                            <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                                <Storyboard x:Key="repeatSb" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red"   />
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="Transparent"/>
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                                <Grid>
                                 <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                       Stroke="Transparent" Fill="#FFFBD0D0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />                                                                      
                               </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="repeatSb_BeginStoryboard" 
                                        Storyboard="{StaticResource repeatSb}"/>
                                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="False">
                                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="repeatSb_BeginStoryboard"/>
                                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: i'll try this approach 10x , i'll accept your answer after iv'e tried it out .